# Why is this regex returning more groups than it should?

Tags: regex, perl

I was going through a popular book on regex and found this piece of regex, which is supposed to pick out values from a line containing comma-separated values.

This is supposed to handle double quotes, with `""` being treated as an escaped double quote (the sequence `""` is allowed within another pair of double quotes)

Here's the perl script I wrote for this:

```
$str = "Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,\"10,000\",\"It's \"\"10 Grand\"\", baby\",10K";
#$regex = qr"(?:^|,)(?:\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")+)\"|([^\",]+))*";
$regex = qr!
        (?: ^|,)
        (?: 
            "
                ( (?: [^"] | "" )+ )
            "
            |
            ( [^",]+ )
        )
    !x;

@matches = ($str =~ m#$regex#g);
print "\nString : $str\n";
if (scalar(@matches) > 0 ) {
    print "\nMatches\n";
    print "\nNumber of groups: ", scalar(@matches), "\n";
    for ($i=0; $i < scalar(@matches); $i++) {
        print "\nGroup $i - |$matches[$i]|\n";
    }
}
else {
    print "\nDoesnt match\n";
}
```

This is the output I'm expecting (which is also what's expected by the author, as far as I can make out):

```
String : Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,"10,000","It's ""10 Grand"", baby",10K
   Matches
   Number of groups: 7
   Group 0 - |Ten Thousand|
   Group 1 - |10000|
   Group 2 - | 2710 |
   Group 3 - |10,000|
   Group 4 - ||
   Group 5 - |It's ""10 Grand"", baby|
   Group 6 - |10K|
```

This is the output I'm actually getting:

```
String : Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,"10,000","It's ""10 Grand"", baby",10K
   Matches
   Number of groups: 12
   Group 0 - ||
   Group 1 - |Ten Thousand|
   Group 2 - ||
   Group 3 - |10000|
   Group 4 - ||
   Group 5 - | 2710 |
   Group 6 - |10,000|
   Group 7 - ||
   Group 8 - |It's ""10 Grand"", baby|
   Group 9 - ||
   Group 10 - ||
   Group 11 - |10K|
```

Could someone please explain why are there empty groups in the actual output (apart from the one before 10,000, which is expected)? 
I copied the regex directly from the book, so is there something else I'm doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Some casual books aren't so good in today's world. Like Mastering Regular Expressions by J. Friedal .. mostly outdated.

Comment: Any suggestions for up-to-date regex books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex has 2 capturing groups and several non capturing groups.  When you applied the regex to the string, you used the **g** modifier tells it to continue to match as many times it can.  In this case the pattern matched 6 times each time returning the 2 captured groups for a total of 12 elements in the array.

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:!
        (?: ^|,)

        (?:

            "

                ( (?: [^"] | "" )+ )

            "

            |

            ( [^",]+ )
        )
    !x)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  !                        '!\n        '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                           '\n\n        '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  "          '\n\n            "\n\n                '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                               ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^"]                     any character except: '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         ""                      ' "" '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                               ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  "          '\n\n            "\n\n            '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                             '\n\n            '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                               ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^",]+                   any character except: '"', ',' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                               ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                             '\n        '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       !x                  '\n    !x'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TLP already mentioned you could also use the Text::CSV module.  Here's that example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1, eol => $/, allow_whitespace => 1});

while (my $row = $csv->getline (*DATA)) {
    print Dumper $row;
}

__DATA__
Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,"10,000","It's ""10 Grand"", baby",10K;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Ten Thousand',
          '10000',
          '2710',
          '',
          '10,000',
          'It\'s "10 Grand", baby',
          '10K;'
        ];
```

Comment: Just a heads-up. Is `(?-imsx:!..!x)` a new Perl regex syntax (> 5.10) ? The `!` aside, `-ism` are the default global modifiers. `-x` in this cluster group context strips any expanded global context scoped in this group, making all the formatting literal (including newline).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but, I'm still a bit confused.

Let's consider just the first value - Ten Thousand. My understanding is that the first capturing group won't match this, but the second will. 

Do you mean that, even though nothing was matched in the first group, a group will still be created, but will just be empty (and so on for each group where nothing was matched)?

Comment: Changed my code a bit to exclude printing 'undef' values in the array. This filtered out all those extra 'matched' groups. So, it looks like a group will always be created even if a match doesn't occur for that group. In Perl (haven't tested this in other languages), such groups will have 'undef' value in the array. I'll accept the answer provided by @Ron as correct, as it helped me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the Perl 5 core module [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) useful. It does all you are trying to do with just a few lines of code. Also note that you can use the `q()` and `qq()` to emulate single and double quote so that you do not have to escape quotes. They can also be used with pretty much any punctuation character, as most perl quote-like operators.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = q(Ten Thousand,10000, 2710 ,,"10,000","It's ""10 Grand"", baby",10K);
my @words = quotewords(',', 1, $str);
print Dumper \@words;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Ten Thousand',
          '10000',
          ' 2710 ',
          '',
          '"10,000"',
          '"It\'s ""10 Grand"", baby"',
          '10K'
        ];
```

(Note: The escaped single quote in `It\'s` is from `Data::Dumper`)

If your data is proper csv data, you can use `Text::CSV` instead.

Comment: Thanks @TLP, I'll keep this in mind if I need to write code for parsing CSV in the future. But right now, I'm just trying to understand the regex, and why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @RonBergin. Capture groups are always preserved.
So if you have 2 capture groups times 6 matches, that would produce an
array of 12 elements.

It looks like you want to trim and the way to conjoin the capture groups into one
is to use a *Branch Reset* which will make a parallel pipe.

I don't want to actually change your regex, however, the example below uses
the branch reset with some robust additions.

```
 # (?:^|,)(?|\s*"((?:[^"]|"")*)"\s*|\s*([^",]*?)\s*)(?=,|$)

 (?: ^ | , )                     # BOL or comma
 (?|                             # Start Branch Reset
      \s* 
      "
      (                               # (1 start), Quoted content
           (?: [^"] | "" )*
      )                               # (1 end)
      "
      \s* 
   |  
      \s*                             # Whitespace trim
      ( [^",]*? )                     # (1), Optional Non-quoted content
      \s*                             # Whitespace trim
 )                               # End Branch Reset
 (?= , | $ )                     # Lookahead for comma or EOL
                                 # (needed because content is optional)
```

Comment: Thanks @sln, this gives me the expected output, and, introduced me to something new in regex (Branch Reset) :) I'd +1 this, but, don't have enough rep right now to do it.